# How to get actual element from document fragment?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a template like so:

```
<template id="my-template">
   <div></div>
</template>
```

That I convert to document fragment like so:

```
const elementFragment = document.getElementById("my-template").content.cloneNode(true);
```

And then I add this element with append:

```
document.body.append(elementFragment);
```

Now the issue is that I need a reference to the appended element, but the reference I have is only a Dogument-Fragment instead of being a HTLMDivElement.

How can I get the actual DOM element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#Avoiding_DocumentFragment_pitfall): use `firstElementChild` to get the first (and in this case only) child of the template, which is an actual `Element` node.

```
const elementFragment = document.getElementById("my-template").content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If your template consists of multiple elements, you'll need to wrap them in a `<div>` or other container element.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Fragment object, you will see that it inherits from the `Node` object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

This means you can use the instance properties and methods like `append`, `prepend`, `querySelector` etc.

Here is how you can get the first node and first element:

```js
const firstChild = fragment.firstChild;
const firstEl = frament.firstElementChild;
```